# Robot Framework ellipsis concatenate adding commas

Tags: robotframework

In Robot Framework when I try and use the ellipsis to put a long statement on multiple lines it is adding a comma at the break.

```
${Built_query} =  Set Variable  select oid, activityCode, activity_description from tblActivity 
...  where ACTIVITY_ENDDATE is null order by oid
```

And that's 4 spaces ellipsis and two spaces.

the result is:

```
'select oid, activityCode, activity_description from tblActivity', 'where ACTIVITY_ENDDATE is null order by oid'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Sam.

Comment: I have been told that the only way to do a true concat across lines is to use RegEx to remove the commas. Seems like too messy a prospect for me.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `...`, each line represents one or more arguments to the keyword. In your case, `Set Variable` is seeing two separate arguments. When `Set Variable` gets more than one argument, it creates a list.

If you want to create a string that is spread out on different lines, you need to use [Catenate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Catenate). With `Catenate` you can define what is used to join each line. By default it uses a single space.

```
${Built_query}=  Catenate  
...  select oid, activityCode, activity_description from tblActivity 
...  where ACTIVITY_ENDDATE is null order by oid
```

Here is a complete test, which passes when run:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${Built_query}=  Catenate
    ...  select oid, activityCode, activity_description from tblActivity
    ...  where ACTIVITY_ENDDATE is null order by oid

    Should be equal
    ...  ${Built_query}
    ...  select oid, activityCode, activity_description from tblActivity where ACTIVITY_ENDDATE is null order by oid
```

Comment: Sorry but it still puts in a comma.

Comment: @SC_Adams: no, this code does not add a comma. It absolutely will put a space between "select..." and "where...". I've updated the question to include a complete test which passes.

Comment: My apologizes - it does indeed. Don't know what I was seeing.